# Celery circular import

Tags: python, celery

I'm using celery in a streamlit application, and whilst reading the documentation the [example](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/next-steps.html) they present doesn't make sense to me - it seems that it will always result in a circular import error

The project structure is

```
proj/__init__.py
    /celery.py
    /tasks.py
```

celery.py

```py
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('proj',
             broker='amqp://',
             backend='rpc://',
             include=['proj.tasks'])

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

How can this work? In the file named `celery.py` the class `Celery` is intended to be imported from the `celery` package - but this is shadowed by the fact that the module itself is named the same as the package (i.e. celery) so instead it tries to import `Celery` from `celery.py`

I'm wondering if I missing something here - or are the examples simply wrong? Most of the unofficial tutorials avoid this by using names like `celeryapp.py` or `tasks.py` so I'm a little confused how why it's like this in the official examples?

Comment: proj/__init__.py
    /celery.py
    /tasks.py

could u please edit the celery.py file name and try

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you're asking - my question is "is the official celery example wrong" not how do I get this code to work,

Comment: In ur project directory u have created a file called celery.py right? Could u pls change that file name to something else and re run?

Comment: I don't think you're understanding the question - this isn't my code, its the official tutorial from celery (see the link in ther question).  I know how to get it to work by renaming celeray.py. My question is - is the celery documentation wrong as written.

Comment: I code is correct. But while running this code in python wont work since they have used the package name as the file name. Its working for me only after editing the file name

Comment: Yeah so the example cannot work as written? I'll raise a bug with them